# install windows 8 in GPT style hard disk

Tags: uefi, gpt

I have an Acer Aspire E15 laptop, of my friend, in which I have been trying to install Windows 8 but I am unable to do so.
It has 4 partitions:

```
Partition 1: total: 900MB - free: 900MB - type: Primary
Partition 2:  total: 128MB - free: 128MB - type: MSR
Partition 3:  total: 447.9GB - free: 447.9GMB - type: Primary
Partition 4:  total: 16GB - free: 16GMB - type: Recovery
```

When I select partition 3 to install OS it says "windows cant be installed because it is GPT type" or something similar.
How do I install in this partition?

Additional info:
-without installation disc it shows "no bootable device- insert boot disc and press any key" so cant restore or repair.
BIOS:
-boot mode selected : Legacy (when switched to UEFI it says "no installation disc is inserted)
-HDD name and serial numbers are visible in BIOS.

How do I fix this issue? Do I need other installation media? or do I have any problem with my HDD?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have booted from disc in non-UEFI mode.

Make sure that CSM is disabled in your BIOS settings and when choosing the boot device, it should have `UEFI:` listed before the DVD drive name.

Another thing I would recommend is to make a bootable USB without MBR by using Rufus or the manual method from [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html). If you can boot from it, then sure it is in UEFI mode.

Comment: How do I disable CSM? I did not find any option to disable Compatibility Support Mode (CSM) in BIOS menu :(

Comment: @imRen it works no matter the CSM setting, but by disabling it you are sure booting in UEFI mode.

Comment: I created a UEFI bootable pendrive (formatted as FAT32) and changed the BIOS Boot Mode to UEFI but now I am getting this error: "we couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one"

Comment: PROBLEM   SOLVED.
probably i was getting this error - "we couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one", because i forgot to take the Windows 8.1 Installation disc out before installing from pendrive.
thank you guys. you all rock.

Answer (score 2):

In order to install Windows on a GPT disk, use Rufus to create a bootable USB stick with settings like in the picture below:

It is important to choose "**GPT partition scheme for UEFI**"

[image: Rufus settings]

This solution fixes the error:

> windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style

Comment: you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Either

- boot your DVD or pendrive in EFI mode and install to a GPT partitioned  disk
- or boot with backward compatability mode (CMS) and install to a MBR partitioned disk.

In your case you booted in old mode and tried to install to the new disk format. Windows does not support this. Boot from EFI mode (disable CSM is possible and boot from a windows 8 or more modern DVD or from a FAT formatted pendrive with /boot/boot.efi file, not an NTFS formatted one), or boot in the old mode and repartition the disk (diskpart, select disk X, clean).